# VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest slow on Intel MacBooks

Tags: swift, machine-learning, vision

I have a very simple feature that tries to remove the background from a web camera video stream using VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest and VNImageRequestHandler.
On Mac computers with M1 processors works great (60-120 fps without any issue). The same code/app on MacBook Pro Intel i7 2.7GHz and Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 the performance is only 10 fps, much lower.

Here is the used code:

```
let personSegmentationRequest = VNGeneratePersonSegmentationRequest()
personSegmentationRequest.qualityLevel = .balanced
let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage) // a frame from the camera

try? imageRequestHandler.perform([personSegmentationRequest])
guard let result = personSegmentationRequest.results?.first else {
      return nil
}
```

Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Have you checked with the profiler that these lines are causing a drop in performance?

Comment: Yes, those lines alone can run at 10FPS on Intel MacBooks. On M1 MacBooks it can run at 60-100 FPS (same lines, same app, different output).

Comment: I understand that if we pass the preloaded asset as an image, and not the image from the camera, it will also be such a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I don't know if it will change anything but it's worth trying to replace vision request into CIPersonSegmentationFilter

Comment: CIPersonSegmentationFilter is not documented anywhere.. CIFilter(name: "CIPersonSegmentationFilter", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: ciImage]) should work? I receive nil in this case.

Comment: The Iris Plus 655 is really old. The M1 is new, amazingly fast, and more or less specifically engineered for this kind of work. I don't find a factor of 6-10 surprising at all.